# I can not seem to figure out why I can't convert to an int

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to convert an string into an int but for some reason it does seem to want to work. I am very interested in learning where there is a disconnect in my understanding of the code written. Thank you!

```
def fourdigitnum(num):
    string = str(num)
    while (len(string) < 4):
        string = "0" + string
    return string
def ascend_desend(string,order):
    if(order == "ascend"):
        string = sorted(string,reverse = True)
    elif(order == "descend"):
        string = sorted(string,reverse = False)
    return string
def list_to_num(lst):
    string = ""
    for ele  in lst:
        string = string + ele
    return int(string)

def KaprekarsConstant(num): 
    num = int(num)
    count = 0
    while num != 6174:
        num = fourdigitnum(num)
        #ascend and descend are lists
        ascend = ascend_desend(num,"ascend")
        descend = ascend_desend(num,"descend")
        #they must be turned into nums
        ascend = list_to_num(ascend)
        descend = list_to_num(descend)
        num = descend - ascend
        count += 1

    return count

print KaprekarsConstant(raw_input())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/576159006/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    print KaprekarsConstant(2111)
  File "/tmp/576159006/main.py", line 33, in KaprekarsConstant
    ascend = list_to_num(ascend)
  File "/tmp/576159006/main.py", line 16, in list_to_num
    return int(string)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '999-'
```

Comment: What is 999- ? Do you mean -999?

Comment: What's the input data?

Comment: please give us the input you are using exactly as you type it

Answer (score 0):

In your code the calculation in line `num = descend - ascend` returns the negative(-) value, because generated `ascend` values is greater than `descend`. You can take absolute value and continue from here see below lines:

```
num = descend - ascend
num = abs(num)
count += 1
```

Comment: @Fanatique  The answer is correct, because when he makes **num=descend-ascend** gets a negative value. In the next iteration, when he makes the list from the number, he gets the - sign in the last place (because of sorting), so it converts it to 999- is incorrect, and  gets an error when you try to convert it to an integer

Comment: @nacho You are right, I did not notice it was a cycle, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the calculation at line 15.

Seems like in your code, the value of 'string' being calculated at this line is getting the value '999-' which cannot be converted to integer type since it has a '-' in it.